# Creating a github check run attaches results to only first actions run

Tags: javascript, github-actions, github-api, octokit

An action performs an octokit request to create a check run:

```
const context = require('@actions/github').context;

octokit.rest.checks.create({
  ...context.repo,
  name: name_task,
  head_sha: context.sha,
  status: 'completed',
  conclusion: 'success',
  output: {
    title: 'Results',
    summary
  }
});
```

I checked if there's a way to bind a check run to a specific action run but I don't see a way to do so based on the docs: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/checks/runs?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-check-run

Basically what happens is that I have 2 workflows triggering by a push. The check run can get assigned to either of them, and usually it's the one that triggered first which is pretty random. Then, if you do a rerun another check will get created on the base run that was first performed. I'd like to assign a check run to a specific run of a specific workflow, is it possible?

Comment: This is perhaps a misinterpretation of the display, the check run is per commit, not for a dedicated workflow. So while you may create a check run within a workflow, this may also come from somewhere totally different. This is why it may appear random when looking at them on the workflow level (IIRC especially when you create them finished, not enqueued), a better overview then is in the pull request view (or elsewhere where you have them with the commit they belong to).

Comment: @hakre I see, I thought so I was wrong about the interpretation of the feature. It's just they appear on the actual runs and I thought they may be used as a run summary of some sort.

Comment: Yes, they appear there (when created by a workflow). And I think its good we can see them there. I don't have an example at hand but IIRC the setup I have in mind I was also initially puzzled. My workflow was creating a check run for every commit in the workflow,. I got more overview when I started to create them first, queing them up. And then later when starting to process the actual commit, mark them as started (might be the wrong verb here) and then when done finished. On the build-run overview they should be always on the left then. But right, with multiple workflows, which one to take?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use a different `name` for different check runs. Otherwise only one of them will be shown in GitHub's UI.

Comment: Where exactly they are shown in the Github's UI? Are you talking about their appearance in the runs? And what does "one" mean, does that mean that across separate runs only one mention of the check may exist? I need to settle the ambiguity.

Comment: they are shown at the end of each open pull request, you should see a list of commit statuses and or check runs that belong to the pull request's last commit. Each check run / status is in the format "<suit name> / <check name>". If you create two check runs for a commit with the same name, only one of them will be shown in the list.